Disabling / Removing / Excluding / Collapsing * Allele SNPs indicating an Overlapping Indel
I am trying to find a way to disable the reporting of Spanning or overlapping deletions (* allele) within the GATK trio genotyping pipeline or a way to properly deal with SNPs given the * allele.
I am tempted to just delete all the lines with this, because the definition given by GATK insinuates that there must be an upstream INDEL that spans a SNP site, but after extracting just the patient from the trio phased VCF, I find overlapping SNPs being called on the other allele without an upstream deletion on that same allele:
#CHROM  POS         REF   ALT     GT
chr1     154590148   CG  C      0|1
chr1     154590149   G   *      1|0
chr1     154590149   G   C      0|1

Here is another example but straight from the trio VCF and with more details directly pulled from the trio VCF- I put ** around the phasing information - the proband is in the final column:
chr2    213147679   .   CAA C   PASS    **0|0**:89,7:96:52:21:21:0|1:213147679_CAA_C:0,21,2979:0,52,3045:213147679  **0|1**:73,9:82:62:21:21:0|1:213147679_CAA_C:93,0,2513:62,0,2569:213147679  **0|1**:76,13:90:99:21:21:0|1:213147679_CAA_C:229,0,2565:198,0,2621:213147679

chr2    213147681   rs6738070   A   C   PASS    **1|1**:0,89:96:52:1|1:213147679_CAA_C:3857,364,0:3881,373,0:213147679  **0|1**:1,72:82:91:1|0:213147679_CAA_C:3874,422,122:3867,400,91:213147679   **0|1**:0,76:90:99:1|0:213147679_CAA_C:3746,559,229:3739,537,198:213147679

chr2    213147681   rs6738070   A   *   PASS    **0|0**:0,7:96:52:1|1:213147679_CAA_C:3857,2862,2979:3881,2905,3045:213147679   **1|0**:1,9:82:91:1|0:213147679_CAA_C:3874,2444,2486:3867,2456,2521:213147679   **1|0**:0,13:90:99:1|0:213147679_CAA_C:3746,2516,2565:3739,2528,2600:213147679

These alleles are not recognizable by downstream applications...
